# How to add AppSync backend to AWS MobileHub project via console?

Tags: aws-mobilehub, aws-appsync

Although `awsmobile-cli` has a feature for enabling and configuring an AppSync backend like:

```
awsmobile appsync enable
awsmobile appsync configure
```

It is prone to end up with a total irrelevant configuration: It creates DynamoDB tables in us-west-2 (Oregon), even if my project is located at eu-central-1 (Frankfurt). And it does so through its default "events" graphql schema. And after all, it does not appear on the MobileHub project console as a *backend feature*.

Now, the thing I want to do is **adding an AppSync backend to AWS MobileHub project via the console**. And then I can pull the changes from the *cli* once I am done i.e. modified the my graphql schema, attached the resolvers and engaged the datasources.

Is it possible as of now?

Comment: Facing similar problems. Is it at all possible to change the auto-config? I was hoping to add an existing appsync easily

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately right now this is not possible via the Mobile Hub console. It is in the CLI roadmap to support importing existing AppSync resources.

Comment: It'd be perfect if you can share where to keep the track of the roadmap you've mentioned -if there's one available.

Answer (score 1):

As it is not possible to on Mobile Hub right now you could try to use [serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) together with [serverless-appsync-plugin](https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin). It allows you to write your infrastructure as code and to deploy it to AWS via CLI.

While Mobile Hub is kinda limiting, you can actually design more complex backend for your app with serverless tool. You can even set up lambda data sources for appsync. Here you can find some examples for different graphql API setups: https://github.com/serverless/serverless-graphql

If you have more or less complex schema it is a right solution to deploy it from CLI as AppSync console starts to lag with big schemas